# AngularJS equivalent of v-el

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

I just found the v-el directive in Vue.js which is a great convenience for DOM-manipulation.

F.ex. I could mark an element with it:

`<button v-el="getCustomerButton">Get customers</button>`

and in the vue component use for example  `this.$$.getCustomerButton.focus()` to focus the button.

Is there some equivalent to v-el in angularjs?

Regards, Niels.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that same result with the following directive:

```
angular.module('yourModuleNameHere').directive('vEl', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
        // do whatever you want with element
        // just element is the jqLite-wrapped object
        // element[0] is the raw DOM node
    }
  };
}]);
```

Also note that `element` is wrapped as a jqLite object, if you want the raw DOM node, you can get it with `element[0]`.

In general, when you've applied a directive to an element, you can access that element in the `link` function.

Comment: That's right, however that would require a new directive for each element marked. Therefore two different actions would require two different directives, which I find unflexible. V-el can be reused for many different actions.

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass the `$event` variable to `ngClick`, `ngBlur` etc, and get the element with `$event.target`.